# PHP reading a link via xml with special characters

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file that is editable via a webpage where users enter links. This looks like

```
 <links>
    <link1 path="http://abc.def.com/abcd?id=2&ed=4" > </link1>
 <links>
```

I read this xml via php and then add a button which will link here. What I'm currently doing is use a `str_replace('&', '&amp;',)` on the xml string and then a `str_replace('&amp;', '&',)` on the extracted path. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: take a look at [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) and [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)  functions

Comment: You can also use [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) or [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) to encode the whole URL in a common standard.

Comment: @Teneff I tried using htmlspecialchars and echo'd the resultant value. It looks identical, I'm not seeing any &amp's

Comment: @Aks take a look at [this example](http://codepad.org/ujE4gHfJ)

Comment: @Teneff strangely even that doesn't show amp's in my page. Is html eliminating it when displaying?

Comment: Yep, when there is `&amp;` in your HTML you will only see `&` in your browser. If you want to display `&amp;` to the user you will have to have `&amp;amp;` in your code

Comment: But my xml still throws an error, its not doing it for me

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown is not an XML file. An XML file cannot contain an unescaped ampersand.

The URL as stored in the XML should encode ampersand as `&amp;`. When you read the XML file the XML parser will present you with the unescaped text, that is `&`. Of course, if you try to read the XML file without doing proper XML parsing, you will be in a mess, as you deserve to be.